# Refresh JWT once across mulitple browser windows/tabs

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs

I have some code set up that refreshes JWT tokens successfully. A problem arises when the user opens multiple tabs, and they all trigger to refresh the tokens at the same time. Each tab gets new tokens that are different from each other and only the latest one will actually work. How can I run the token refresh function once across all browser tabs?

Comment: You know server can't tell which tab a request came from but session id will be the same so you may keep track of *token *,* session id*, *timestamp*  when a "refresh my token" request arrives just check your lookup table whether you have recently generated a token for this session id, if yes then return the old one else generate new and store it in your lookup alongwith session id and timestamp.

Comment: @Viney Unfortunately it is a third party that handles the tokens, so I don't have control over the server.

Answer (score -1):

I figured this out. First think first you should store your token in local storage. Then when you request refresh token you should set first the Authorization header with the token in local storage then request it to the server. this is mandatory for getting up to date token. after you request, you will get response new token from server. set the new token to local storage and set the Authorization header (as default) with the new token. This way works for me.

```
  created() {
    const vm = this;
    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      function(response) {
        if (response.headers.authorization != undefined) {
          localStorage.setItem(
            "token",
            response.headers.authorization.replace("Bearer ", "")
          );
          axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
            response.headers.authorization;
        }
        return response.data;
      },
      function(error) {
        if (error.response.status == 401) {
          vm.$store.dispatch("logout").then(() => {
            this.$router.push("/login").catch(err => {});
          });
        }
         return Promise.reject(error);
       }
    );
  },

  async mounted() {
      while (this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 60000)).then(v => {
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
          "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token");
        axios({ method: "get", url: "/login/refresh" });
      });
    }
 }
```